# Change Controller to Not Error on Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple Show in my Users Controller. This just shows a list of that User's posts and comments. However if the user doesn't have any posts, I get an error:

```
Couldn't find post with 'id'=101.
```

I understand the error, because there are no posts associated with that user, but how can I change my Users Controller to still function as it should (show posts and comments associated with a user) and not throw an error if posts = nil. For instance for a new user.

The issue isn't with my view, as I've completely deleted that and the error still throws. I originally tried to add an if user.posts? line, but the problem occurs before the view.

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @user.posts.mostrecent.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comments = @post.comments.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

I think I'm mudding up my controller, but this is the only way I got posts and comments to show correctly. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Solution (kind of)**

Added a Rescue to stop error from throwing if there are no posts:

```
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    posts = nil
```

Comment: You're getting both the `@user` and the `@post` from the same `params[:id]`. So one of them is wrong, and judging by the error it's the `@post`. What is the URL that's calling this? What's the route? You should pass the id for the post as a separate parameters such as `post_id`, so you can use `params[:post_id]`.

Answer (score 2):

this doesn't make sense in your controller

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
...
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

The @user and @post would not have the same id except under some amazing coincidence. The @post **would** have a `user_id` that would match the user's `id` field.

If you want to retrieve a post that belongs to the user, you can do...

```
@post = Post.find_by(user_id: params[:id])
```

This will retrieve the first post it finds for the user, and it will return nil (without error) if no post exists.

Comment: Because @comments = @post.comments.paginate(page: params[:page]).

Throws an error if the post variable isn't defined, but there's got to be a better way than what I've got.

Comment: And is it possible a user has no posts? If so you need to cater for that. Only do the comments retrieval if  `@post` is not null.